# How to reverse a LINQ to SQL query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I want to reverse the output of a LINQ to SQL query.
and .Reverse() does not work, just crashes the page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NewsDataContext db = new NewsDataContext();
    var News = from news in db.News                   
               select new 
               {
                   ID = news.NewsID,
                   kort = news.Short
               };

    foreach (var newa in News)
    {
        Panel1.
        Controls.
        Add(new LiteralControl(newa.kort + 
                               "</br>" + 
                               "<a href=Full.aspx?id=" + 
                               newa.ID + 
                               ">Read The full Article</a>"));
    }
}
```

Is there another way to reverse it?

Comment: *"....Reverse() do not work, just crashes the page."* - How about telling us the cause of the crash?  `Reverse()` works, sounds like a problem in your code.

Comment: it said "The query operator 'Reverse' is not supported."
but its solved now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing SQL Server doesn't know how to translate Reverse into a T-SQL command, so you're getting an exception.  You'll probably need to pull the results of the query down from the database, **then** reverse it.

```
var News = (from news in db.News                   
               select new 
               {
               ID = news.NewsID,
               kort = news.Short
               }).AsEnumerable().Reverse();
```

Comment: @StriplingWarrior and @DaveShaw's answers are much better as the *general* solution to this question.

Comment: Adding the appropriate sort clause to your query is definitely the appropriate way to solve your particular problem.  Just make sure you're aware when you're query is getting executed on your database (where Reverse will blow up) and when you're in memory, and have full access to all of the linq methods

Answer (score 14):

If it's news you are trying to show, why not use an OrderBy (or OrderByDescending) to get the items in the order you want rather than the reverse order of the clustered index in the database.

I cannot think of any case where I would need to use Reverse in Linq to Sql.

Example (sorry if the Syntax if off, I prefer Lamda's):

```
var News = 
     (from news in db.News   
     orderby news.Date descending                 
     select new 
         {
               ID = news.NewsID,
               kort = news.Short
         });
```

Comment: If you need to sort by another field next (i.e Date then Id), you can just comma separate the fields (or if you are using Lamda's, then "ThenBy").

Comment: Then why does SQL Server have a REVERSE function?

Comment: @micahhoover - that [reverses a string](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180040.aspx), not the order of a set.

Answer (score 5):

The question is: What are you reversing?

The SQL store doesn't define a specific order on the News table, so simply "reversing" the results of a query without any defined ordering doesn't make sense.

How about something like this?

```
var News = from news in db.News    
           order by news.PostedTime descending               
           select new 
           {
               ID = news.NewsID,
               kort = news.Short
           };
```